# Fixtures loadModel does not load properly when the yml file contains Object with Map refer to another object

Tags: java, playframework

init-datasample.yml

```
Book(a): &a
  title: Play in Action
  price: 30.00

Book(b): &b
  title: Alice in Wonderland
  price: 12.00

Person(b):
  name: Bob Joe
  ratings:
    ? *a: 8
    ? *b: 8
```

Java Class Definition for Person

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Person extends Model
{
    public String name;

    // choice and importance score
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Integer.class)
        @MapKeyClass(Book.class)
    public Map<Book, Integer> ratings;
}
```

The Fixture.loadModels("init-datasample.yml") does not load the initial ratings defined in the above. I tried not to put &a, &b, it didn't work either. Could someone please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got the work around. Would like to share here. And if anyone can take a look and think it is worth commit to the git source, please help to do so.

The problem is the embedded is not support at this moment. So the resolveDependencies in the Fixtures class does not resolve the reference in the map defined.

My work aorund is to extend Fixtures class, and hide the loadModels methods. And
inside the code block of

```
Fixtures.loadmodels(String name, Map<String, Object> idCache) {

... ...
                            if (f.getType().isAssignableFrom(Map.class)) {

/* new below */
                                    ElementCollection ec = f.getAnnotation(ElementCollection.class);
                                    MapKeyClass mkc = f.getAnnotation(MapKeyClass.class);
                                    if (ec != null && mkc != null) {
                                        Map mapper = (Map) objects.get(key).get(f.getName());
                                        if (mapper == null) continue;
                                        Class targetClass = ec.targetClass();
                                        Class mapKeyClass = mkc.value();
                                        Map<Object, Object> fieldValue = new HashMap();
                                        for (Object k : mapper.keySet()) {
                                            Object mapKey = retrieveObject(mapKeyClass, k, idCache);
                                            Object targetValue = retrieveObject(targetClass, mapper.get(k), idCache);
                                            fieldValue.put(mapKey, targetValue);
                                        }
                                        f.set(model, fieldValue);
                                    } else {
                                        f.set(model, objects.get(key).get(f.getName()));
                                    }
                                }

... ...

}

/* new method below */
private static Object retrieveObject(Class targetClass, Object alias, Map<String, Object> idCache)
    {
        if (targetClass.isAssignableFrom(alias.getClass())) {
            return alias;
        }

        Object targetValue = idCache.get(targetClass.getCanonicalName() + "-"+ alias);

        if (targetValue != null) {
            targetValue = Model.Manager.factoryFor(targetClass).findById(targetValue);
        }else {
            try {
                targetValue = targetClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(alias.toString());
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        return targetValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, someone wanted to refer to an already existing entity (whitch was loaded in an earlier @OnApplicationStart for example) you can refer them by the ids:

Fixture:

```
User(user01):
  email: user01@g.com
  userGroup.id: ${models.UserGroup.getGroupForYml(models.UserGroup.GROUP_SALES)}
```

UserGroup Model:

```
@Entity
public class UserGroup extends Model {

    public static final String GROUP_ADMIN = "admin";
    public static final String GROUP_CUSTOMER = "customer";
    public static final String GROUP_SALES = "sales";

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userGroup")
    public List<User> userList;

    @Column(name="groupId")
    public String group;

    /**
     * Used in the yml fixtures
     * @param group - the group id
     */
    public static Long getGroupForYml(String group) {
        UserGroup ug = UserGroup.find("byGroup", group).first();
        return ug.id;
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseModel {
    publis String email;

    @ManyToOne
    public UserGroup userGroup;
}
```